# How to find relationships between financial data?

Tags: time-series, econometrics

Suppose I have a time series of stock growth and one of gdp growth and education over the years.

Can I try to explain stock using gdp and education by running an OLS or would I be mistaken from a formal (not content) point of view?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by *formal* but if you have intuition into why gdp or your education metric should be related to the growth of stocks, then by all means, build a model that tries to find the relationship between them.

OLS is one way to find a relationship between gdp and education relative to stock growth.  There would be nothing wrong with that concept in general.

That said, there are many things you could do wrong in setting up your model.  You may want to share more in order to get more help.

Comment: I just wanted to know that I could use OLS for time series and I guess you have said I can: <<OLS is one way to find a relationship between gdp and education relative to stock growth. There would be nothing wrong with that concept in general.>>. Do I need all time series to be stationary?

Comment: You don't "need" to have them all be stationary in the sense that nothing stops you from running the model.  Is it better if they are stationary, yes.  But sometimes it's impractical.

Comment: Because I have read here on stackexchange that if they are not stationary it is garbage... the problem is that I am struggling because if I make them stationary I have horrible results

Comment: Theres a very fuzzy line between what's practical and what's theoretically ideal.  You have to get to know your data and develop intuition and theory on how and why it should behave in certain ways.  Then you test your theories.  [this site](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~magpn/Research/LSTS/TOS.html) provides some good information as well.  If you are just going to poke and prod and hope you find something useful, then you have to be careful not to abuse the theoretical assumptions.

Comment: But I have the economic interpretation... but how can I justify the fact that I am running OLS with non stationary data?

Comment: depends on the degree of non-stationarity.  [You've probably see this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/94727/114499) And its true.  If you've already run the models you want after taking the diffs, and found no information.  That may indicate that there is no information.

Comment: do you think that if I have three time series $x,y,z$ that are non stationary I could have better results by regressing the one I want to explain ($x$) not only on $y$ and $z$ but also on $x$ lagged? In this way am I risking not to give the right importance to the other two factors? (that are included also in $x$ lagged?)

Comment: Who is the audience for this work? The answers will be different if it is an academic or research setting where the process is of very high importance vs an investment setting where results and usability matter far more.